# What does "CCs" stand for?

Tags: phrase-meaning, abbreviations

Chadd E. Hunt tweeted:

> And this my friend is why you do not ride bicycles, **mopeds or anything under 400 CCs** on a road that has commercial traffic. You will literally get swept up and dropped by the turbulence around you by passing traffic. Why planes wait several minutes between takeoffs.

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/chaddehunt/status/1456563839634452483)

What does CCs stand for? "Carbon Capture and Storage"? If so, the "s" should have been capitalized. It might refer to "cubic centimeter (of waste gas)" - I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context "CCs" refers to **cubic centimeters of [engine displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_displacement)**.

Comment: Sounds stupid. I have a 1974 350cc Honda CB350F and I ride on all kinds of roads and in all kinds of traffic. Lots of fools on Twitter.